# "ResourceNotFoundException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current" user when fetching user info from facebook

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, spring-boot, spring-social

I keep getting a `ResourceNotFoundException` when trying to fetch user information from facebook using Spring Social.

The flow is: in the client, the user is prompted to log into facebook. The client gets a facebookUserId and sends it to the server. At the server side, I try to connect to facebook and fetch the info:

```
    ConnectionFactory<Facebook> connectionFactory = connectionFactoryLocator.getConnectionFactory(Facebook.class);
    Connection<Facebook> facebookConnec = connectionFactory.createConnection(new ConnectionData("facebook", facebookUserId, "", "", "", "", "", "", null));
    Facebook facebook = facebookConnec.getApi();
    byte [] image = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfileImage(ImageType.LARGE));
```

At this point, an exception is thrown.

```
org.springframework.social.ResourceNotFoundException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
        at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler.handleFacebookError(FacebookErrorHandler.java:89) ~[spring-social-facebook-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler.handleError(FacebookErrorHandler.java:59) ~[spring-social-facebook-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
```

Being, in the code above, `connectionFactoryLocator` an autowired bean that I configure as shown [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/connecting.html)

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator() {
    ConnectionFactoryRegistry registry = new ConnectionFactoryRegistry();
    registry.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(
            environment.getProperty("spring.social.facebook.appId"),
            environment.getProperty("spring.social.facebook.appSecret")));
    return registry;
}
```

I'm positive that `appId`, `appSecret` are correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don’t send the user id to the server - that is more than easy to fake. Send the user access token instead - and then use that to request the user’s details, via `/me`

Comment: @CBroe Thanks but my original problem is that I don't know how to get the access token at server side. That's why I'm trying to connect this way.

Comment: Well that depends on your client-side implementation, and how the FB login part is handled.